# Update a row in Oracle SQL that has been copied from the same table without effecting previous row

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Right now my table `Batch_relations` has columns such as `Batch_name`, `Batch_size`,...

I want to be able to create a copy of a row from this table (already done) and then update that row without changing the row that is was copied from.

For example, let's say I have a `batch_name` called testBatch and the batch size is 3. After copying it, I will have two rows, both with the name testBatch and a batch size of 3. It will look something like this:

| batchName | batchSize |
| --- | --- |
| testBatch | 3 |
| testBatch | 3 |

If I want to add 2 to one of the batches, so that now the rows will be (If one batch is larger than the other, we want to update the batch that has a larger value)

| batchName | batchSize |
| --- | --- |
| testBatch | 3 |
| testBatch | 5 |

How would I accomplish that?

This is my current SQL query:

```
UPDATE BATCH_RELATION
SET BATCH_SIZE = ?
WHERE (BATCH_NAME, BATCH_SIZE) = (
    SELECT BATCH_NAME, BATCH_SIZE
    FROM (
        SELECT BATCH_NAME, BATCH_SIZE
        FROM BATCH_RUN_RELATION
        WHERE BATCH_NAME = ?
        ORDER BY BATCH_SIZE DESC, ROWID
    ) 
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1
)
```

After this is run, it will change both values so that the table will look like this instead

| batchName | batchSize |
| --- | --- |
| testBatch | 5 |
| testBatch | 5 |

What query could I use to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`merge` is one option.

Before:

```
SQL> select * From test order by batch_name, batch_size;

BATCH_NAM BATCH_SIZE
--------- ----------
Batch2             8
testBatch          3
testBatch          3
```

Update `batch_size` for one of `testBatch` rows:

```
SQL> merge into test a
  2    using (select batch_name,
  3             max(rowid) as rid
  4           from test
  5           group by batch_name
  6          ) b
  7    on (a.batch_name = b.batch_name)
  8    when matched then update set
  9      a.batch_size = 5
 10      where a.rowid = b.rid
 11        and a.batch_name = 'testBatch';

1 row merged.
```

After:

```
SQL> select * From test order by batch_name, batch_size;

BATCH_NAM BATCH_SIZE
--------- ----------
Batch2             8
testBatch          3
testBatch          5          --> here it is

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  You should/must do it by adjusting the value of batch_size as you create/clone the record.  if you make no changes to any columns when you copy the row, then you have no logical way of differentiating the rows.

This is where having a PK is really REALLY important:

without a PK, you have to change value first ... (and hope it doesn't duplicate another row):

```
insert into batch_relation
   ( batch_name, batch_size )
   select batch_name, batch_size + 2
     from batch_relation
     where batch_name = ?
/
```

but with a PK of "id" ... you just copy the row, and assign the next ID to it:

```
new_id = seq.next_val;

insert into batch_relation
   ( id, batch_name, batch_size )
   select :new_id  id, batch_name, batch_size
     from batch_relation
     where batch_name = ?
/

update batch_relation
  set batch_size = batch_size + 2
where id = :new_id
/
```

(although even with PK, it's still obviously more efficient to adjust the values on the insert ;) but if you really NEED to have the clone FIRST, then the update LATER .. you really need to have a PK there, and have a clean identifier to the new row).